# My AlarmDemo keeps crashing with unclear reasons in my logcat

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

I am learning how to use the AlarmManager to set up notifications but when I run this, the app crashes, not sure why. Could anyone take a look at it and see what's wrong, please?

This is my MainActivity.java file

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

 private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 50);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);

} //end onCreate
}
```

this is my MyReceiver.java

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
    context.startService(service1);

}
}
```

This is my AlarmService.java file

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;


public class MyAlarmService extends Service
{

private NotificationManager mManager;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
}

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
{
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);

    Notification notification;
    CharSequence from="AlarmDemo";
    CharSequence message="This is a test message!";
    //= new Notification(R.mipmap.ic_launcher,"This is a test message!", System.currentTimeMillis());
    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this.getApplicationContext(),0, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Notification.Builder builder=new Notification.Builder(MyAlarmService.this);
    builder.setAutoCancel(false);
    builder.setContentTitle(from);
    builder.setContentText(message);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent);
    builder.build();
    notification=builder.getNotification();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    mManager.notify(0, notification);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

And this is my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".MyAlarmService"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver"/>
</application>
```

This is what my logcat says

```
09-10 15:09:36.259    7105-7129/com.example.androidalarmmanagerdemo E/eglCodecCommon﹕ writeFully: failed: Broken pipe
09-10 15:09:36.259    7105-7129/com.example.androidalarmmanagerdemo W/libEGL﹕ eglInitialize(0xa3788040) failed (EGL_SUCCESS)
09-10 15:09:36.259    7105-7129/com.example.androidalarmmanagerdemo I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-10 15:09:36.259    7105-7129/? E/EGL_emulation﹕ tid 7129: eglChooseConfig(533): error 0x3001 (EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED)
09-10 15:09:36.259    7105-7129/? W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
09-10 15:09:36.259    7105-7129/? E/EGL_emulation﹕ tid 7129: eglChooseConfig(533): error 0x3001 (EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED)
09-10 15:09:36.259    7105-7129/? A/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to choose config, error = EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
09-10 15:09:36.259    7105-7129/? A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2,    fault addr 0xb74be62c in tid 7129 (RenderThread)
```

Comment: Logcat of actual crash?

Comment: Please post the stack trace of the exception, the output that you posted has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: thats all thats in my logcat :/

Comment: How about you not set your alarm to be 1 day in the future (24*60*60*1000 milliseconds) and just make it a minute or two to see what happens.

Comment: Are you running on emulator? You could run this app before implementing the Alarm? This fatal signal occurs while rendering the app and appears have nothing to do with your code. If you are running on an Emulator, try to create another one and see what happens.

Comment: @MorrisonChang i put it to run once everyday

Comment: @ThiagoMoura it worked! i changed the emulator and eventually it worked! thank you

Comment: @droidnoob nice! GL with your development :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fatal signal occurs while rendering the app and appears have nothing to do with your code. If you are running on an Emulator, try to create another one and see what happens.